# TypeError: The comparison function must be either a function or undefined

Tags: eslint, type-error

В WebStorm библиотека ESLint ругается и выдает ошибку

> TypeError: The comparison function must be either a function or undefined

Жму на детали и вижу что ссылка идёт на такую функцию:

```
function getAcceptableSlots(memberInfo, orderedSlots) {
    return orderedSlots.map(function (slot, index) {
        return { index: index, score: scoreMember(memberInfo, slot), sort: slot.sort };
    }) // check member against each slot
    .filter(function (_ref3) {
        var score = _ref3.score;
        return score > 0;
    }) // discard slots that don't match
    .sort(function (a, b) {
        return b.score - a.score;
    }) // sort best matching slots first
    .filter(function (_ref4, i, array) {
        var score = _ref4.score;
        return score === array[0].score;
    }) // take top scoring slots
    .sort('index');
}
```

Конкретно ругается на строку
.sort('index');

Есть у кого-нибудь идеи что это может быть и как поправить?

Comment: _как поправить?_ не передавать в функцию, которая ожидает функцию, строку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) в качестве параметра принимает функцию.

В данном случае идет попытка передать строку: `.sort('index')`, так как строка не является функцией - и появляется указанная ошибка линтера, а так же ошибка при выполнении данной команды.

Для решения нужно просто передать функцию, по аналогии с тем, как это уже было сделано тут выше:

```
.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.score - a.score;
}) // sort best matching slots first
```

---

Исходя из переданной строки, скорее всего имелась ввиду сортировка по полю `index`, следовательно можно вставить тот же код что и выше, заменив `score` на `index`

```
.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.index - a.index;
}) // sort best matching slots first
```

<s>Однако в этом случае сортировка по score теряет смысл.</s> Хотя нет, не теряет, так как перед этим фильтруется по максимальному значению `score`.

Comment: Спасибо, это я и так понял. А какая логика была задумана в sort('index') ? Т.е. функцию то я создать как понял, а что внутри её писать не очень понимаю.

Comment: @МихаилСтепнов, _А какая логика была задумана в sort('index') ?_ - это надо спросить у тех кто это писал, чтобы точно знать что имелось ввиду.

Comment: В этом и есть основной вопрос Grundy. Тех, кто писал давно нет и никто не может подсказать, что же значит sort('index').

Comment: @МихаилСтепнов, тогда можно только гадать, если нет никакого описания что именно должна делать данная функция.

Comment: @МихаилСтепнов, судя по комментариям, тут просто ищется максимальный положительный `score`, а потом выбираются все элементы с таким скором.

Comment: Я понял, спасибо, ща потестим!